# How to code to get data from multiple tables using C# and SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have this code which returns the correct data from one table. But I have related data in other tables using `INNER JOIN`. So my question is how to code to return this in the result?

```
IList<Schedule> GetCurrentValues()
{
    var result = new List<Schedule>();

    using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(_configuration["DefaultConnection"]))
    {
        sqlConnection.Open();

        using (var command = sqlConnection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = "SELECT Schedules.AppointmentHeading, Schedules.AppointmentDateStart, Schedules.AppointmentDateEnd, Bookers.Email, Rooms.Id AS Expr3, Rooms.Name " +
                                  "FROM Schedules " +
                                  "INNER JOIN Rooms ON Schedules.RoomId = Rooms.Id " +
                                  "INNER JOIN Bookers ON Schedules.BookerId = Bookers.Id";

            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        // How should I code so I also get Bookers.Email and Room.Name?
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Your code is returning columns from three tables, so if the code is correct (as you say it is), then it is doing what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you need a mixed data from different tables, it is recommended to either create new Model which will consist of the properties you actually care like

```
AppointmentHeading, AppointmentDateStart, AppointmentDateEnd, BookingEmail, RoomName
```

or just add BookingEmail & RoomName to your existing **`Schedule`** Model.

```
using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(_configuration["DefaultConnection"]))
    {
        sqlConnection.Open();

        using (var command = sqlConnection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = "SELECT Schedules.AppointmentHeading, Schedules.AppointmentDateStart, Schedules.AppointmentDateEnd, Bookers.Email as BookingEmail, Rooms.Id AS Expr3, Rooms.Name as RoomName" +
                                  "FROM Schedules " +
                                  "INNER JOIN Rooms ON Schedules.RoomId = Rooms.Id " +
                                  "INNER JOIN Bookers ON Schedules.BookerId = Bookers.Id";

            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                          result.AppointmentHeading = Convert.ToString(reader["AppointmentHeading"]);
                          result.AppointmentStart = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["AppointmentDateStart"]);
                          result.AppointmentEnd = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["AppointmentDateEnd"]);
                          result.BookingEmail = COnvert.ToString(reader["BookingEmail"]);
                          result.RoomName = Convert.ToString(reader["RoomName"]);

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you @Viresh. I wanted to have those tables separated but as it seems to work to have the extra columns in the exisiting Schedule model, I'll go with that for now.

Answer (score 2):

Just reference the column names in the `SqlDataReader` - it returns a "flat" set of all the columns selected, and you can access these via the column name (or the column alias `AS ....` if one is given). Then store those values as needed, e.g. in a separate class or whatever works for you:

```
....
using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        // read the individual values and store them as needed
        string appointmentHeading = reader["AppointmentHeading"];
        DateTime appointmentStart = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["AppointmentDateStart"]);
        DateTime appointmentEnd = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["AppointmentDateEnd"]);
        string email = reader["Email"];
        string roomId = reader["Expr3"];
        string roomName = reader["Name"];

        // possibly create a custom class here to hold these values
        // and store the multiple possible rows returned into a list of those classes 
        // - or do whatever you need to do with these values here.....
    }
}
```

Comment: Great! It seems to work if I add .ToString() at the end of the reader["x"]

Comment: I can still not get this new data to be updated on my webpage. the return-statement can only return the data for the IList<Schedule>. I get the 'Cannot implicitly convert type...' error.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new class containing all the columns of select statement.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question about how to get from the reader to that class

Comment: This should be an comment not an answer!